# problem with android library project - classes not found

Tags: java, android, library-project

I think i do not understand Android Library Project correctly. I'm having the following issue:

1. i have a library project in a package `a.b.c.lib`
2. i have a application which is uses the library project in package `a.b.c`
3. i have another application which is uses the library project in package `a.b.c.pro`

Everything is OK with the application in package `a.b.c`, however i hit the following issue (during runtime) in the `a.b.c.pro` app:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a.b.c.lib.c1$c2`

the same class is found OK in the `a.b.c` app.

So, what is the right way to define packages in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no right way. Every way is right. It should work so I think the problem is not in packages. Do you use Proguard for obfuscation? It can remove some classes which are used in your app. Also such errors happen because of some bugs in the toolchain. Try to clean and rebuild you app .

Comment: No proguard (at least i do not know i configured it). I did clean several times, the problem is during runtime, compilation looks OK.

Comment: Do you have a proguard folder inside the bin folder?

Comment: Are AndroidManifest.xml files the same in both projects? And what's the logcat output?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have no idea what was the issue, i'm not going to pursue the problem, i've copied the code :((. Sorry and thanks, i'm deleting the question - unfortunately i'm not able to delete.

Comment: when you did not find correct answer, please do not accept it. it misguide others. please keep it open as its an imp. question.